# 1970s European comic series in which alien invaders of Earth self-destruct in a nuclear holocaust of their home planet

Tags: story-identification, comics, alien-invasion

I think it was an Italian comic but I could only read the last of its installments in a Spanish magazine published by Bruguera. A second possibility is that it was a French or British one.

According to that last issue, Earth's defense forces have been waging a defensive war against alien forces that look like the Mekon-ruled Treens aliens in the British comic Dan Dare: short, thin, green humanoid aliens with big heads.

These aliens came from an extrasolar planet called "Ut" and had a forward base on the Moon to direct their invasion. The comic book protagonists had some secret friends among the aliens who formed a pacifist faction.

One day, the Earth forces discover that the aliens have stopped their attacks and have abandoned their base on the Moon. An Earth expedition goes to the aliens' home planet (called Ut if I remember correctly) and they discover that the planet is completely dead. There is a satellite orbiting it with a message for the protagonists dictated by one of their pacifist alien friends who, if I remember well, was named Erg or Egg.

In this message Erg tells that the pacifist faction had successfully orchestrated a coup to depose the tyrant leader but the latter had detonated the entire thermonuclear arsenal on the planet as revenge. Erg is soon to die from radiation sickness and has sent this satellite into space to say goodbye to his Earth friends.